# I cannot install simle-react-dropdown

Tags: reactjs, npm

I am trying to install react-simple-dropdown by typing the following command in GitBash in the project directory: 
`npm i react-simple-dropdown`

When I run that I get the below errors:

```
$ npm i react-simple-dropdown
lease-tracker@0.1.0 C:\Lease_Tracker
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react@16.2.0
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react-dom@16.2.0
`-- react-simple-dropdown@3.2.0

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.1.3 (node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN react-simple-dropdown@3.2.0 requires a peer of react@0.14.x || 15.x but none was installed.
npm WARN react-simple-dropdown@3.2.0 requires a peer of react-dom@0.14.x || 15.x but none was installed.
npm WARN simple-react-dropdown@3.3.0 requires a peer of react@^15.3.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN simple-react-dropdown@3.3.0 requires a peer of react-dom@^15.3.1 but none was installed.
```

Could you please help me out with this?

Thanks,
Emir Kobaslic

Comment: They are just warnings. You can ignore them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are just warnings not errors .